# Open fileLocation For Input As #1

Tags: excel, vba

what does `As #1` stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the file number - see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209231).  Looks like you should request this number using another function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233118/vba-exists-function-without-giving-any-error

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов **Page Not Found!** :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a file number.

Using file numbers is the "old BASIC" way of doing file I/O. Consider using the FileSystemObject classes instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233118/vba-exists-function-without-giving-any-error